# Kdb+ : how to control permissions and entitlements

Tags: kdb

Can someone please advise how can we control permissions and entitlements in kdb+ to ensure the data/tables are properly access controlled?

I understand there is -U user param for specifying the user/password, but the challenge is around table level permissions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add simple authentication by doing:

```
-U /path/to/password.txt
```

This file contains user:password where password is result of in q md5"password" and strip off 0x in front.

For more sophisticated authentication then you can change the `.z.pw` and `.z.ac` hooks

Answer (score 0):

check this [paper](http://www.firstderivatives.com/lecture_series_pp.asp?downloadflyer=q_for_Gods_July_2013) out from First Derivatives. Might help